# State and Scroll position restore Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have an app which fetches posts from a site using a API and then displays it. There are three navigation options, which are basically filters.

The problem is, whenever I switch to another navigation tab (I'm using bottom navigation bar), it ends up rebuilding the whole page, meaning it will fetch all that data again and it might potentially contain new data.

What I want to do is to keep restore this data in a way that is fast and my **initState()** doesn't get called(because that is what fetches the data). I did try using all the different kind of keys but I cant get it to work.

**Main page:**

```dart
class AppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  AppHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppHomePageState createState() => _AppHomePageState();
}

List<Widget> _navs = [
  BestPostsRoute(key: PageStorageKey("bestP")),
  HotPostsRoute(key: PageStorageKey("hotP")),
  NewPostsRoute(key: PageStorageKey("newP"))
];

class _AppHomePageState extends State<AppHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  onTap(index) => {
        setState(() => {_currentIndex = index})
      };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      /* appbar ... */
      body: _navs.elementAt(_currentIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          /* nav items */
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**One of the three pages(the code is similar in all three):**

```dart
/* imports... */

class HotPostsRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  HotPostsRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HotPostsRouteState createState() => _HotPostsRouteState();
}

class _HotPostsRouteState extends State<HotPostsRoute> {
  late PostInstance postInstance;
  List<Post> _posts = [];
  bool _loaded = false;

  fetchPosts(String? after) async {
    var stream = postInstance.front.hot(limit: 10, after: after);
    await for (UserContent post in stream) {
      Submission submission = post as Submission;
      Post pPost = Post(submission);
      pPost.parse().then((value) => setState(() {
            _posts.add(pPost);
          }));
    }
    setState(() {
      _loaded = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        redditInstance =
            Provider.of<PostInstanceState>(context, listen: false)
                .getInstance;
      });
      fetchPosts("");
    }
  }

  // Fetches and generates posts
  Widget _buildPosts() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _posts.length + 1,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        if (index < _posts.length) {
          return _buildPost(_posts.elementAt(index));
        } else {
          fetchPosts(_posts.last.fullname);

          return SpinKitDualRing(color: Colors.white);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // A singular post
  Widget _buildPost(Post post) {
    print(post.object);
    return PostCard(post, key: ObjectKey(post.object)); // .object just creates a map of all fields
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {});
    return Container(
      child: _loaded ? _buildPosts() : SpinKitDualRing(color: Colors.white),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you'd want to learn is state management: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options . To keep things simple, you could learn provider first then bloc later. State management allows you to manage your state (your var) between multiple screens (multiple .dart files). To store and control the scroll position, you can use a ScrollController and store and load the position using it

Comment: I do know state management(I used provider in the given example aswell), however i am debating whether or not i should use it. I know about how keys are used to restore state and so i thought it would be better to use those, as obviously these posts are being stored in a **List** and don't need to be accessed anywhere other than the one page they belong to. I am not sure about how good of a idea it is to store 3 Lists containing potentially hundreds of Posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kept searching and eventually a post on **Medium** led me to the **IndexedStack** Widget.

Its a widget that is made from the **Stack** widget and basically loads and stores the state of all its childrens. Unlike **Stack**, it shows its children one at a time and thus is perfect to use with **BottomNavigationBar**.

Here's the [Blog post](https://medium.com/@flutterhive/keep-state-of-widgets-with-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-bb732214bd11) for anyone looking out.